# Open pdf with evince in orgmode link

Tags: org-mode, openwith

When i click or `C-c C-o` on pdf link in org-mode, Emacs opens the pdf with gimp.

I don't find how to overide this behavior.

Tried with these two recipes

```
(require 'openwith)
(openwith-mode t)
(add-to-list  'mm-inhibit-file-name-handlers 'openwith-file-handler
(setq openwith-associations '(("\\.pdf\\'" "evince" (file))))
```

With first recipe, no change on behavior

```
(org-add-link-type "pdf" 'org-pdf-open nil)

(defun org-pdf-open (link)
  (let* ((path+page (split-string link "#page="))
         (pdf-file (car path+page))
         (page (car (cdr path+page))))
    (start-process "view-pdf" nil "evince" "--page-index" page pdf-file)))
```

With second recipe, no change in behavior

Can you help me ?

Best regards

Comment: Please explain what happened with each one of those two "recipes".  BTW, I only see one "recipe".

Comment: inline change, for the two recipes with result after change. Thanks

Comment: I'm pretty sure I've heard of people having similar problems (PDF handled by Gimp) where the culprit was linked to Emacs's handling of mailcap settings.  Maybe a `M-x report-emacs-bug` is in order.

Answer (score 0):

It might still be using the mailcap system and gimp somehow has the highest priority in `/etc/mailcap`.  To fix this for you user override it in `~/.mailcap` by putting this there:

```
application/pdf; /usr/bin/evince %s; test=test "$DISPLAY" != ""; description=Portable Document Format; nametemplate=%s.pdf
application/x-pdf; /usr/bin/evince %s; test=test "$DISPLAY" != ""; description=Portable Document Format; nametemplate=%s.pdf
```

You can also do this system-wide by editing `/etc/mailcap` directly, there are instruction on how to do this in this file safely since this is also automatically updated when packages are installed or removed.

Answer (score 0):

You can add `(setq org-file-apps '(("pdf" . "evince %s")))` to your config. Here is an example with additional apps:

```
**** Associate extensions with applications to open
#+begin_src emacs-lisp 
  (setq org-file-apps
      '(("docx" . "abiword %s")
    ("doc" . "abiword %s")
    ("epub" . "foliate %s")
    ("gnumeric" . "gnumeric %s")
    ("mp3" . "vlc %s")
    ("m4a" . "vlc %s")
    ("pdf" . "evince %s")
    ("xlsx" . "gnumeric %s")
    ("xls" . "gnumeric %s")
    ))
#+end_src
```